# Deploying an MVC in IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7.5

I have some Problems about deploying an MVC-site.

What I did:

Install Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Add the IIS 7.5 Feature

Install .Net 4

Register .net in the iis, using "aspne_regiis -ir"

Add a new Application at the Default Web Site

Choose my application

Choose the DefaultAppPool

call up localhost/test in the IE

The Problem:

 The Site is not correctly presented

 e.g. The text is not presented in the right colors but only in black

 there are no Images shown

 the dll's, located in the applicationfolder are not used


 Here two pictures what it is supposed to look like and what it actualy looks like

[what it looks like](http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3167/fudkdl8x_png.htm)

[what it is supposed to look like](http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3167/evizpioe_png.htm)


I used different "how to's" about this topic but could not find my mistake.

So what do I have to do to display the Site correct?


Tanks.

Comment: How did you deploy your MVC application to IIS from Visual Studio?

Comment: I did not deploy it by using the VS. (The deveopment machine is not the machine where it is supposed to run)
I deployed it by copying the release folder to the inetpub and choose that folder in the IIS as new application

Comment: Try using Visual Studio Publish > Publish to your Desktop (or any folder) > copy the entire published set into the IIS Server

Comment: I tried but its the same result

Comment: Hmmm. I'm out of ideas now. Usually it would be the App Pool settings or Deployment errors.

Comment: An Workmat found the Answer. The StaticFileHandler for .css (or other static file types) was missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Workmate found the Answer. The StaticFileHandler for .css (or other static file types) was missing and needed to be included.